# FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58: when copied to shared hosting service

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I copied my laravel project to a shared hosting site and I got this error

> FatalErrorException in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58: App\Modules\Products\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::App\Modules\Products\Providers{closure}(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bellamage-cakes\app\Modules/Products/Routes/web.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php56/usr/share/php')
>
> in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58

I've tried `composer update` and `composer install` but nothing seems to work. I get the same error in the terminal but when I run `composer install` I also get this error

> Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error
>     [RuntimeException]
>     Error Output:

Answer (score 0):

> Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\bellamage-cakes\app\Modules/Products/Routes/web.php'

Do not use hardcoded paths as I pretty much doubt this valid path on your hosting.

Comment: Thanks to you I think I might have found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcin Orlowski for pointing out the complete obvious that if it was a snake it would have bit me and I'm so grateful for that because thanks to that I realised that the problem was my config cache and all I had to do was remove it.

Thank you so much again I appreciate it alot. In future I will do better at reading the errors.